# How can I apply the loop statement into the temp table in sql?

Tags: sql

I have the following code to run a loop to insert the date rage into the tamp table, and this is working fine:

```
;WITH testOne([dDate], Leave)
AS
( 
   SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-06') 'dDate', 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,ad.dDate), 1
   FROM testOne ad
   WHERE ad.dDate < CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-08') 
)
```

The result will be look like :

```
aDate       Leave
2013-05-06  1
2013-05-07  1
2013-05-08  1
```

However, when I trying to insert the records into the tamp table like the following, it's seem not working for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #testTwo 
(
    dDate date,
    Leave int 
)



INSERT INTO #testTwo 
        ( dDate, Leave )
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-06') 'dDate', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,ad.dDate), 1
FROM #testTwo ad
WHERE ad.dDate < CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-08')
```

The result will be look like :

```
aDate       Leave
2013-05-06  1
```

Any way that I can insert the same record like the 1st code with the 2nd code by using tamp table #test?

Comment: question makes no sense. You can't select out of an empty table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is a special construct called a "recursive common table expression". This is *not* a temporary table, just a special kind of query which can recursively (or, iteratively) refer to its own output.

As far as I'm aware, this is the only way in pure SQL (i.e. not an embedded procedural language) to achieve recursion of this kind.

What you don't show is actually using the recursive CTE for anything. If you want to insert that result into a table, you just need to carry on using that CTE, but with an insert statement. I'm not sure exactly what DBMS you're using, so can't confirm that this will be the exact syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
WITH testOne(dDate, Leave)
AS
( 
   SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-06'), 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,ad.dDate), 1
   FROM testOne ad
   WHERE ad.dDate < CONVERT(DATE, '2013-05-08') 
)
INSERT INTO #testTwo ( dDate, Leave )
SELECT dDate, Leave
FROM testOne
```